# docker command not found in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

[image]
[image]
[image]

I am trying examples from Jenkins website https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/hello-world/ for learning Jenkins. I installed Nodejs and Docker plugins and created a pipeline project. I got `docker: command not found` error. Can someone please help me in solving the issue?

Comment: Does the `docker` command work if you just run it from the command line, completely outside of Jenkins?

Comment: @JosephSible I installed Jenkins on my mac and docker running on my machine.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. When you run the `docker` command on the command line on the same computer that Jenkins is installed on, what happens?

Comment: @JosephSible Both Jenkins and docker are installed on the same computer. When I type docker on the terminal, I got usage guide with a list of available options